# How to install a newer version of the GTK libraries?

Tags: upgrade, gtk

I want to install a newer version of the GTK libraries so I can mess around with the new GtkHeaderBar (I want to try to make applications).

I have Xubuntu 13.04 and currently have version 3.6 of those libraries. How do I update to a higher version? I have tried the `gnome-next` ppa but when I try to upgrade with it, Synaptic says I have to remove a lot of packages, `xubuntu-desktop` included...

I have tried the deb's from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/3.8.4-0ubuntu3/+build/5062175) as well (3.8 instead of 3.10, alas), but those didn't install because the one deb needed the other so couldn't install, but that other deb needed the first deb too so can't install too, making it impossible to install them.

I have tried the packages from http://www.gtk.org/download too. It compiles and installs without errors, but when done with installing, it isn't installed... It does mess up the appearance of many GTK application though until `make uninstall`'ed.

How do I upgrade the GTK libraries?

Comment: Why the downvote?